# Colab : Best way to create a copy/clone of notebook in Goolge Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using the Goole colab for data analytics and I have several notebooks.
Sometimes I need to quickly make a copy/clone of my working notebook to make some changes and experiment.
So is there a quick easy way to like a shortcut or menu option to do this? other than downloading the notebook as a .ipynb file and loading again with new name?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can make a copy from the menu

```
File > Save a copy in Drive...
```

The new Colab will be named `Copy of xxxxx.ipynb`. You can click the name and rename it.